# Create New Column containing value based on conditions on date and hour

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-embedded

I have a table in my power BI with the following fields :

[image]

Preview of the data:

[image]

- The column "platform" has 3 possible values : application, shop, website
- "day" is of type Date
- "hour" is of type "Date/Time" (same information as "day" + has the hour)

I added a measure to calculate the conversion_rate (orders/visits):

```
conversion_rate = DIVIDE(SUM(Table[orders]), SUM(Table[visits]))
```

Then I calculated for every day the conversion_rate **from 7 days ago** (to be able to compare them):

```
conversion_rate_7_j = CALCULATE(Table[conversion_rate],
                         DATEADD(Table[day],-7,DAY)
                       )
```

Now my data looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is calculate the conversion rate from **7 days ago but for the same hour.**

However I couldn't find a function that substracts field of type Date/Time while taking in consideration the hour.

A solution I thought of is to calculate orders and visits **-7 days same hour** separately and then divide them to have the conversion rate -7 days same hour:

```
orders_7_j_hourly = 
    VAR h = Table[hour] - 7
    VAR p = Table[platform]
    Return CALCULATE(
     MAX(Table[orders]),
     Table,
     Table[hour] = h,
     Table[platform] = p
    )
```

Since my data is grouped by hour (Date/Time) and platform,

And since sometimes for a certain hour I have values for the platform = "application" but not "shop",

My function did not work especially that I am using MAX, this associated the number of orders to the wrong platform.

Can you please help ?

Sample data : https://ufile.io/y1blqgqn

Comment: any chance you can provide a sample data ?

Comment: What if you make 2 columns from your column Hour to Hour_date and Hour_hour? Now you have hour value in separate column and you can easily apply additional Group by on Hours. Is that make sense?

Comment: @mkRabbani my problem with the "platform" would still exist, since every value of "hour" is repeated X times (X = number of platforms, sometimes 3 and sometimes less)

Comment: Then show sample data for all possible scenarios. And then add your expected output from them. Please avoid adding image for sample data.

Comment: @mkRabbani sample data added to original post

Comment: @smpa01 yes, sample data added to original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datetime values are stored in units of days. Thus you can simply shift `hour` by 7 in your measure.

```
conversion_rate prev_week =
VAR CurrHour = SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[hour] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [conversion_rate],
        ALL ( Table1[day] ),
        Table1[hour] = CurrHour - 7
    )
```

Sample results:

[image: Table visual screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use HOUR function ??

```
conversion_rate_7_hour = CALCULATE( [conversion_rate],
FILTER( ALL(Table),
                         SELECTEDVALUE(Table[day]) - 7 = Table[day]
&&  HOUR(SELECTEDVALUE(Table[hour]) - 7) = HOUR( Table[hour])
                       ))
```

When we put Table[hour] to visualization it should work.

Ps. best pratice => if your refer to measures in your calculations,do not include the table prefix

Comment: This didn't work, returned an error : DAX error: A function ‘SELECTEDVALUE’ has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed.

Comment: add FILTER( ALL(Table),  and aditional ")" on the end

Answer (score 0):

You can create an additional column called `hour` in your dataset
[image: s1]

Once you have that, you bring the hours in the viz, the following measure can give you what you want

```
convRate-7 = CALCULATE([convRate],DATEADD('Table'[day],-7,DAY))
```

[image: S2]

Comment: Your solution works when displaying the info in a table like your example! But when i try to visualize it, I cant do that with day + hour. Do you have a solution?

Comment: Can you please provide your expected output in table for me to understand what do you want? You want the calculation to happen on day->hour level, but you don't want to display the hour in the viz. Do you want this hours in a slicer then? Please let me know.

Comment: This is the output I have : https://ibb.co/vVDMWmH  But what I want is to display the axis Y = conversion_rate AND conversion_rate_7J, and axis X = date+hour.